# Modify Data in columns in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, function, oledb

I have an excel with user details. How can I loop through each row and remove special characters in number values?

*User Input*

```
name      age   phone number
Dipin     2,3   12345-67890
Nikhil    24,   12345-67891
Adarsh     25,  12345-67892
Sreejith   2,6  12345-67893
```

*Desired Output*

```
name       age  phone number
Dipin      23   1234567890
Nikhil     24   1234567891
Adarsh      25  1234567892
Sreejith    26  1234567893
```

Any Solutions?

Comment: What format is the file ? What is the file extension? "An excel" is not very descriptive, and the advice we'd give changes depending on if it's a CSV, xlsx etc

Comment: What does an age of 2,3 mean? Is it some typo you're looking to clean up?

Comment: the extention is .xlsx and the age is something I want to cleanup. Its supposed to be 23 but there may be cases in which we received data is corrupted